# net::ERR_ABORTED 404 NextJs While Production

Tags: next.js

I  am trying to build a Next Js project.But unfortunately i am getting this error message

> net::ERR_ABORTED 404

While Production .Its working fine in Localhost

I think this the part where i am facing the issue

```
  <Link href={`/questions/[questionid]`} as={`/questions/${id}`}>
      <a> Answer</a>
  </Link>
```

Comment: Did you find the solution for it? I need it, I am also facing the same issue